# Remove first element in an array inside another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of arrays that gets returned from a mongo query. I want to take and remove the first item/element in each array. Here is my node route

**Route partial**

```
let queries = [
    User.find({"companyID":req.user.companyID}, (err, foundUsers) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    }),
];
Promise.all(queries)
.then(results => {
    res.render('hr/employees', {header: 'EMPLOYEES', users: results[0]});
}).catch( err => {
    req.flash('error', err);
    res.render('hr/employees', {header: 'EMPLOYEES'});
});
```

**Sample arrays**

*What I have now*

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

*What I want*

```
[[2, 3], [5,6], [8,9]]
```

Comment: Please post your array of arrays. Also from that array of arrays write your expected array of arrays.

Comment: @VicJordan That is pointless. I will add a sample set of arrays but I doubt anyone wants to look at 2k lines of JSON which is what my arrays will hold.

Comment: no one is asking you to post actual 2k lines of json but expect you to post sample structure with lesser lines of code. Hope you understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose `results` is an array of arrays. Use slice inside a map to remove the first element and return the desired array.

```
Promise
  .all(queries)
  .then(results => (results.map(result => (result.slice(1)))))
  .then(adaptedResults => res.render('hr/employees', { header: 'EMPLOYEES', users: adaptedResults[0] });
```

**EDIT:** Using the values you have provided.

```js
console.log([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]].map(arr => (arr.slice(1))))
```

Comment: Thanks, when I plug that into the route it give syntax errors and I don't know `.map` well enough to troubleshoot.  How would I take what you have and then send that result to my `res.render`?

Comment: Thanks for your edit it worked! I had to add a few more `)` but otherwise perfect thank you.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Also, you could do it inside the same .then as follows: .then(results => {
  const adaptedResults = results.map(result => (result.slice(1)));
  res.render('hr/employees', {header: 'EMPLOYEES', users: adaptedResults[0]});
})

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the job,

```
const arrOfArrays = []; // get value from response
// remove first element from all arrays safely
const newArr = arrOfArrays.map(arr => (arr && arr.length) ? arr.shift() : arr);
```

Edit: As @rghossi pointed out, the above snippet should return an array of first elements. So the right way to do it would be,

```
const arrOfArrays = []; // get value from response
// remove first element from all arrays safely
const newArr = arrOfArrays.map(arr => (arr && arr.length) ? arr.slice(1) : arr);
```

Comment: Just gave that a try and tried with a few modifications to it and neither seemed to work. Maybe I will have to try dealing with this issue inside EJS

Comment: @joshk132 I just updated my answer. `.map` will return a new array and you will have to assign it to a new variable to use the updated results.

Comment: @joshk132 Glad to hear that. If you could accept the answer, it'd help others.

Comment: That's actually incorrect. `arr.shift()` will return only the removed element, not the modified array. You could use `slice(1)` instead or change your implementation to return `arr` after `arr.shift()`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `Array.prototype.shift()` is what you're looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

Comment: Yes sorta, I know of shift() but that will just remove the first array in my set of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slice()` and `shift()` method to that easily

```
for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    results[i].slice(1);//OR you can use results[i].shift()
}
```

Or you can modify your code like:

```
Promise.all(queries)
.then(results => (results.map(result => (result.shift())) {
    //OR you can use result.slice()
    //Your code here
});
```

It will remove all first element in an array of arrays.

Comment: I realize that is an option but was looking for a cleaner way of doing it.